# Modules for correlate2d in Python

Tags: python, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between two matrices using [`correlate2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stsci.convolve.correlate2d.html) (code: `corr = correlate2d(im, im, fft = True)`).

`correlate2d` was part of scipy and is now under [stsci_python](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python).

Currently I am loading modules as follows:

```
import scipy
from scipy import *
import numpy as np
import stsci
from stsci import *
```

I get the error `name 'correlate2d' is not defined`. What modules do I need to load for this?

Answer (score 1):

SciPy has correlate2d in the signal sub-package:

```
import scipy.signal
```

followed by:

```
corr = scipy.signal.correlate2d(matrix1,matrix2)
```

SciPy sub-packages need to be imported separately; stsci may be the same.

-Aldo

Comment: I tried scipy.signal.correlate2d and found it extremely inefficient, probably because it does a brute-force element-by-element convolution rather than utilizing Fourier transforms.  I started a script to compute the autocorrelation of a 4096x4096 image four days ago on a capable computer; it's still running with no end in sight.  Not surprising since the brute-force method goes with N**2, so we're talking some 281 trillion multiply and add operations.
In the meantime, I found I could get the desired result in a couple of minutes using the numpy.fft.fft2 and numpy.fft.iff2 functions.

Comment: Thanks for the note! I'll remember this if I have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from scipy.stsci.convolve import correlate2d
```

Or, if `stsci` is available as a top-level module:

```
from stsci.convolve import correlate2d
```

If you are going to do `from stsci import *` for other reasons (although that ["is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)), then you can access the function as `convolve.correlate2d` without adding any new imports.

Comment: Hi @sjy, I tried all your suggestions but none of them worked. `stsci` seems to be available as a top-level module, but I haven't found a way to import `correlate2d` or `convolve` so that I can use it.